# How to create enum in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

> I want javascript functions which take `integer` (**week days[i.e 1,2,3...7 ]**) and return `string` **(i.e 'Sunday','Monday'....)** . but I dont know what are the best way to do this. it means what I should use `enum` or `array` or `switch case`

- Js function
- `function GetFullName(weekDay) {
  if (weekDay == 1)
      return "Monday";

  if (WeekDay = 2)

      return "Tuesday";
  }`
- **But, I dont want to do like this......Is there any smart way to thi using create `Enum` ?**

Comment: Just use an array, if Monday needs to start at 1 use an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
function GetFullName(weekDay)
{
var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
var day = days[ weekDay-1];
return day;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use days as in 1st, 2nd... etc. you will have to add a -1 like `days[weekDay-1];`

Comment: @Spokey You mean `days[weekDay-1]` :)

Comment: @RGraham Yes indeed, simple logic error. Should be -1

Answer (score 2):

Just another thought than array, create an object weekday with dayname and index:

```
var weekdays = {
    Monday : 1,
    Tuesday : 2,
    Wednesday : 3,
    Thursday:4,
    Friday:5,
    Saturday:6,
    Sunday:7

}

function getFullName(weekDay) {
for( var prop in weekdays ) {
        if( weekdays.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
             if( weekdays[ prop ] === weekDay )
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}

var fullName = getFullName(2);
console.log(fullName);
```

Comment: Thanks , this will also help me when my js function take short name instead `int` i have modify it little and it's works for me . If my function is taking  short name like 'Mon','Thu' etc. than this function is useful .